# How do I match a single line in a text, excluding what are before and after?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying a pattern to get the last line of stars from this text.

The pattern I came with is pretty simple. It matches the first and last lines of starts

(*{5,})

However, I only need the last line.
Here's the text:

Some text here

```
  ************************************

  *                                  *





  *                                  *


  * Source: Test                     *


  *                                  *


  * Amount: $6.50                    *


  *                                  *


  ************************************
```

Comment: Is this all in a single string?

Comment: Yes, there are all in a single text. 

There are some text before the first line of star, but nothing after the last line of stars.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the end of a string with `\z`.

So in Ruby format, this would do the trick:

```
"\\*{5,}\\z"
```

Cheers!

That works for me, I've tested it here: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

OK, it really does work:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = " ************************************\n" +
          "*                                  *\n" +
          "*                                  *\n" +
          "* Source: Test                     *\n" +
          "*                                  *\n" +
          "* Amount: $6.50                    *\n" +
          "*                                  *\n" +
          "************************************";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*{5,}\\z");
        // In case you would like to ignore case sensitivity you could use this
        // statement
        // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        // Check all occurance
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output: Start index: 260 End index: 296 ************************************

Comment: I am using java and the same link you use for testing. It does not work

Comment: I am getting what you're trying to achieve here.

I want to only match the last line of stars (***********************).

Comment: That is exactly what the code does. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html "\z: The end of the input"

Comment: This works, but with capital Z

http://www.rubular.com/r/F0kZuWPlmK

Thanks for your help

Comment: Aha! You still had a newline at the end of the line you wanted to match. So it wasn't the last line: The was not the string you put in your question, that one didn't have a newline at the end.

Comment: Also, please don't forget to upvote and accept an answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern `'\*{5,}$'` which matches the end of string. But you need to double-escape the backslash, so `\\*{5,}$`.

```
Pattern.compile("\\*{5,}$")
```

Comment: This will still return the first and last line of stars. However, I only need the last line of stars

Comment: I thought `$` only matches end of *string* (not end of line) *unless* you feed in the `MULTILINE` modifier, which I haven't.

Comment: I did set the multiple flag tag on when testing it

Comment: Well you don't want to have the multiline flag or the regex won't work, as enabling it causes `$` to match embedded end of line as well as end of string.